# Customize FileChooser window - java

Tags: java, swing, applet

I want to customize FileChooser window. Here I want to insert one label and text box, also I stuck how to get inserted value from newly added text box.
Here what I done.

**My CustomFileChooser:**

[image]

**and I need Like :**

[image]

I just extends JFileChooser and using below mentioned code to add components:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("Document Name: ");
        lable.setForeground(Color.RED);
        docText = new JTextField();
        docText.setName("documentNameText");
        docText.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(gl_panel
                .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        docText,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        150,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(lable))
                                .addContainerGap(0, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                Alignment.TRAILING).addGroup(
                gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lable)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(docText, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap()));
        gl_panel.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl_panel.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
        setAccessory(panel);
```

Comment: @Sandhu I have updated my question with my code

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the result with your `GroupLayout`.

But run and check the following program I created. I'll give you the Custom JFileChooser as you need

```
public class CustomJFileChooser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        JComponent panel = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JTextField docText = new JTextField(20);
        docText.setName("documentNameText");
        docText.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Document Name: "));
        panel.add(docText);
        chooser.setAccessory(panel);

        // This part is important
        JComponent center = null;
        BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) chooser.getLayout();
        for (Component child : chooser.getComponents()) {
            if (BorderLayout.CENTER == layout.getConstraints(child)) {
                center = (JComponent) child;
            }
        }
        if (center != null)
            center.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // --------

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("Open File Chooser");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the other answer and I couldn't make it work. Here is how I did it:

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();    

    //get the center component
    BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) fc.getLayout();
    JComponent comp = (JComponent) layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER);
    layout = (BorderLayout) comp.getLayout();
    comp = (JComponent) layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add my panel at the bottom
    comp.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```